# How can I give a customer a non-refundable credit towards their subscription using the Stripe API?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

My app charges premium customers $X.00 per month, however, I would like certain actions to give customers a credit against their monthly subscription fee. For example, if a customer submits a record to the database, they are given a credit (stored in the database). I would like each credit they earn to give them $0.50 off of their next month's subscription, however, if they cancel their subscription, I do not want it to seem like I owe them that money (it should only be usable towards subscription fees). What is the best way to achieve this through the Stripe API?

If it makes a difference, I am using Rails 4, Ruby 2, Stripe, Koudoku for subscriptions, and Devise for authentication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You want to set your app up to handle Stripe web hooks if you haven't already done so. When a new invoice is created, if you have a web hook URL set up, it will notify you via the hook and wait an hour before processing payment. This design is setup for exactly what you want.

When you get notified the invoice has been created, if there are credits for the user, create one or more negative invoice items to represent the credits.

Since you aren't creating the credits in Stripe until right before payment processing, the scenario of them canceling with credit doesn't apply.

You can also of course do other things when adding the negative invoice items for the credits like check to make sure you aren't crediting them more than their invoice total.

Comment: Since posting this I set the app up to adjust the Stripe customer's account balance by -50 ($0.50) each time a submission is accepted. This creates a negative balance in Stripe, but avoids needing to use web hooks, which I haven't explored yet. It also lets me avoid even having to maintain credits on my server. Is there a downside to doing it this way? Can the user refund their negative balance to their credit card? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if they can refund a negative balance or not, but it sounds like this might work for you. You always have control though, so if a refund is requested and the balance is negative, just don't refund it.

Comment: Sounds like that would work as long as I have control over the refunds and I put in writing somewhere that credits are only applicable towards subscription fees. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would give them a [coupon](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions). Coupons can have expiration dates and can be a simple percentage, which would ensure that you would owe them nothing should they unsubscribe. You could just convert your $0.50 to the appropriate percentage.

The api allows you to [create coupons](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#create_coupon) that you can give to users using the [user update](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#update_customer) API:

```
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2"

cu = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_3oLCDGtGqkJElc")
cu.description = "Customer for test@example.com"
cu.coupon = "12OFF"
cu.save
```

Comment: Hey @martin, I looked into this, and you can actually set a coupon for a dollar amount, not just a percentage. That said, I decided not to use coupons because I could not figure out how to apply it to a customer on Stripe via the API, and even when I applied it manually through the Stripe dashboard, I could not figure out how to apply more than one at a time.

Comment: Hey Jack. Just did a quick lookup on the Ruby API, it is perfectly possible to create coupons with the API. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry if my response wasn't clear. Creating a coupon is the issue, applying the coupon to the customer (even once, let alone multiple times like I need to) with the API is what I could not figure out how to do. Thanks again

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense, thanks. However, I still can't use this method, because (as far as I can tell), it only lets you apply one coupon at a time, preventing me from using them like credits (of which can many can be accumulated).

Comment: One option (untested) would be to have different values of coupon, and update them accordingly (ie, if I already have the coupon1 and that you want to give it to me, give me the coupon2 instead, etc).

Comment: Hmm, that seems like it could work, but I think it is overly cumbersome unless the method I went with (described below) doesn't work.